# Floating Figure inside Environment

Tags: environments, diagrams, wrapfigure

I have a problem while trying to use `wrapfigure` or `floatftl` in a typical `Definition` environment. More concretely, I try something like this:

```
\begin{floatingfigure}[r]{5cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{img.pdf}
\end{floatingfigure}

\begin{definition}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  
\end{definition}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
```

but the effect is like typing

```
\begin{definition}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
\end{definition}

\begin{floatingfigure}[r]{5cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{img.pdf}
\end{floatingfigure}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
```

**Is there some way to fix this problem?**

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What problem are you talking about ? Can you provide us a minimal working example so we can try it ourselves ?

Comment: @NNzz Sorry that I have not made a good question. I have changed it; if some further description of the `Definition` environment is needed, let me know.

Comment: An old known problem: `wrapfigure` won't cooperate with lists and (I suspect) your definition structure was built using `\newtheorem`, thus it is a list.